# Java - Changing Servlet Response from Filter

Tags: java, filter, response

I'm trying to append a certain string to every response that is sent back to the client.
For this, I use a filter which looks as follows:

```
public class OutFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        CharResponseWrapper wrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(
        (HttpServletResponse) resp);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

        out.print(wrapper.toString());
        out.print("ADDITIONAL CONTENT".toString());
    }
}
```

I know I can't change the ServletResponse object after the doFilter() Method went through, so that's why I'm using a Wrapper for the HTTP-Response:

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private CharArrayWriter output;
    private ServletOutputStream stream;

    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }

    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
        stream = new ServletOutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }

    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

}
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.foo.OutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/1.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/2.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/3.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/statistics</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The statistics servlet looks like this:

```
public class Statistics extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.getWriter().print("<b>Hello, World</b>");

    }
}
```

The point is to append **"Additional Content"** at the end of the HTTP response of all accessed files, so 1.html, 2.html, 3.html as well as /statistics (which serves the Statistics Servlet).

Accessing the servlet works fine - I get the html content, followed by the "ADDITIONAL CONTENT" string.
However, accessing any one of the static html files yields the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: NO CONTENT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: I don't understand how your filter works. It replaces the writer by a fake one, but doesn't do anything with what has been written to the fake writer. And it doesn't replace the output stream.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my filter. I still run into the same problem though - nothing is appended to the static files, only to the servlet.

Comment: Now you're writing the addendum twice. And you still don't override the OutputStream in the wrapper. The default servlet probably write bytes directy to the response output stream, without using the fake writer. Override getOutputStream(), add debug breakpoints in your filter and wrapper, and see what is called.

Comment: I've updated my post again. My filter now uses its own OutputStream. However I'm still having some issues with the static files. Thanks for your help!